# How to get array 0 value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I was playing with the angularjs for fun and faced some issue.
See the image below

[image]

The data stored in the key 0 and I failed to get those values in array.

```
Example $scope.array[0] retuned undefined
```

Comment: Maybe you are accessing it when data is not available in `array`.

Comment: @Rayon The data is came from `$timeout(function () { return $scope.array.push($scope.payment_methods); }, 1000);` Is this related?

Comment: what is `$scope.payment_methods`?

Comment: @Nitheesh It's data from Ajax call therefore i set $timeout wait for the data return from Ajax

Comment: @erin can you check the answer posted? Is that what you looking for. `watch` works for ajax call responses aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making use of angular [watch](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) function

Hope this will be helpful.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.array = [];
  $scope.payment_methods = ["one", "two", "three"];
  $timeout(function () {
      $scope.array = ($scope.payment_methods);
      console.log($scope.array[0]);
  }, 1000);
  console.log($scope.array[0]);
  $scope.$watch(function(scope) { 
      return scope.array;
    },function(newval, oldval) {
      console.log('From watch -- ', newval, oldval);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"></div>
```

Comment: May I know is it possible to console the values outside of $scope.$watch?

Comment: Yes you can but the `value of the updated list will not be available there` since the ajax calls are asynchronous requests. I have also console the value outside watch but its throwing undefined. Watch function will be triggered every time when there is a change happened in the watching variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
look like 0 is a key inside 'scope' object
here is nothing 'array'
you can access value from object by rule[https://javascript.info/object].
```

```js
let scope = {
    alpha: "alpha",
    beta: "beta",
    0: ["Payment_Cash", "Payment_Credit Card", "Payment_Online Transfer", "Payment_Cheque"]
}

console.log(scope[0])
```